# How to run Power automate flow from Active Batch OR ADF Pipeline

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop, activebatch

I have created manual trigger flow in power automate . i am executing a power bi report and exporting it pdf.

Everything working fine here.

Now my requirement is i want to run this flow from Active Batch or ADF Pipeline.

How to run this.

Can you please help me on this.

Regards,

I am just finding the ways to execute the flow from ADF Pipeline OR Active Batch

Comment: HTTP trigger, not manual button push. Then call it from ADF via the Copy activity.